# TextBlock animation for Opacity not working as expected

Tags: c#, animation, uwp

I have a UWP app project and I am trying to add a couple of `DoubleAnimation`s and I am using below code:

```
private static void CreateStoryboardAnimation(StackPanel sp, ItemHelper item, EnumHelper.AddRemoveFavorites favType)
    {

        var image = (Image)sp.FindName("ImageView");
        var tb = (TextBlock)sp.FindName("FavStatusTB");
        if (image != null)
        {
            image.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
            //tb.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();

            Storyboard tbStory = new Storyboard();
            var tbAnimateOpacity = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = 1.0,
                To = 0.0,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)),
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(tbAnimateOpacity, tb);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(tbAnimateOpacity, "Opacity");
            tbStory.Children.Add(tbAnimateOpacity);

            Storyboard storyboard1 = new Storyboard();
            storyboard1.Completed += async delegate
            {
                // set text
                if (favType == EnumHelper.AddRemoveFavorites.Add)
                {
                    tb.Text = "Added to favorites";
                }
                else
                {
                    tb.Text = "Removed from favorites";
                }
                await Task.Delay(500);
                // run 2nd animation
                var storyboard2 = new Storyboard();
                var translateYAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation()
                {
                    From = -20,
                    To = 0,
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(700)),
                };
                Storyboard.SetTarget(translateYAnimation2, image);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateYAnimation2, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");
                storyboard2.Children.Add(translateYAnimation2);
                storyboard2.Begin();
                tbStory.Begin();
            };
            DoubleAnimation translateYAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = 0,
                To = -20,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(translateYAnimation, image);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translateYAnimation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");
            storyboard1.Children.Add(translateYAnimation);

            storyboard1.Begin();
        }
    }
```

The first time I run the animation it works fine but after that it doesn't. This code gets applied on `GridView` items as you can see below:

[image: Image 1]

The image animation works fine, it goes up and then the `TextBlock` animation runs poorly. It is supposed to display the text for 500 milliseconds but it shows the text and then starts the animation to make the opacity go zero.

I want this text to be visible to the user for at least 500 milliseconds and then the animation should start. Is there something that I am missing? I also tried `BeginTime` property of `DoubleAnimation` but to no avail. Please share your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the fact that you are starting the opacity animation inside the **Completed** handler of the first "slide up" animation. It works the first time, because the `Opacity` of the `TextBlock` is `1.0`, but after the first round it is `0.0` and flips to `1.0` only after the `await Task.Delay(500);` finishes. The easiest fix would be to set the opacity right after the `if`:

```
if (image != null)
{
   tb.Opacity = 1; //add this line
   ...
```